# Rendering Issue for Openstreet Maps with Yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I have had issue previouslys with jquery and Yii and how it renders.

using the following code:

```
<div id="mapdiv" height="1000" width="1000"></div>
<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>

<script>
var mainLonLat = [0.166081 ,38.789011];

map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

epsg4326 =  new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); //WGS 1984 projection
projectTo = map.getProjectionObject(); //The map projection (Spherical Mercator)

var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(  0.166081 ,38.789011 ).transform(epsg4326, projectTo);

var zoom=14;
map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);

var mastsOneK = [new OpenLayers.LonLat(0.154539,38.738778)];

//Create the Circle
circleLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("circleLayer");

circleLayer.addFeatures(createCircle());

function createCircle()
{
    var x = 0;
    var extent = map.getExtent();
    var features = [];
    while(x < mastsOneK.length)
    {
      var threeKStyle = {
      strokeWidth: 1,
      strokeColor: '#FF6600',
      fill: 1,
      fillColor: '#FF6600',
      fillOpacity: 0.4,
      strokeOpacity: 0.4,
     };

      var newThreeK = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
      new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon(
  new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(mastsOneK[x].lon,mastsOneK[x].lat).transform(
  epsg4326, projectTo),
  2000,
  40),"",threeKStyle);

      features.push(newThreeK);

      x++;
    }
    return features;
}

map.addLayer(circleLayer);
</script>
```

I am able to get a map showing with a single circle using just a standard html page, this is the desired result. However, when using the same code and pasting this into a Yii view. The map does not appear. I get a blank white area where the map should be.

If I use chrome inspector and set a height and width to the element (I have set width and height to the element before and this does not make a difference), I can begin to see a slice of the map.

[image]

[image]

If I then zoom in on the page, the full map then appears as expected.

[image]

I have tried to do various workarounds such as resize, redraw, refresh the image etc. Using the codes below and many more for example:

```
$("#mapdiv").resize();


$.fn.redraw = function(){
  $(this).each(function(){
    var redraw = this.offsetHeight;
  });
};


$('#mapdiv').redraw();
```

However the map still does not show. Strangely enough if I remove the DOCTYPE tag at the start of the document, then the map appears, but obviously this causes many other issues.

Could any one suggest why this is happening and any potential fixes they may have come across as I have used every snippet I have got my hands on to no avail.

Similarly when using the highcharts extensions and trying to render the charts in a tab I also get an issue where a zoom in/out is required to see the chart and I can't help but think that the solution to the above would be the solution to this also.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to manually call `map.updateSize()` ( http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.updateSize ) when the containing element size has changed after initialisation.